# select object based on another related object fields

Tags: apex, soql

I have two object Countries and market that are related. One country has many markets but one markets has one country.
Now market have a checkbox field that is focus_year that is selected if we want to focus on it this year or not .

How can I using Apex and SOQL select all the countries that have at least one market with focus_year = True

thx you

this is what I tried: `select id, name from Country where [select Id from Market__c where Focus_Year__c = True].size() > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a sub-query filter:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM Country__c 
WHERE Id IN (
  SELECT Country__c 
  FROM Market__c 
  WHERE Focus_Year__c = true
)
```

The system will first find all matching Market__c records which meet the criteria, then extract the Country__c field to get all the Country__c records that match.